# como criar uma trava no codigo

Tags: python

caso seja digitado a nota errada duas vezes e ele passa pra segunda nota

```
a = int(input('digite a primeira nota: \n'))
if a > 10:
    a = int(input('Nota invalida digite novamente: \n'))
b = int(input('digite a segunda nota: \n'))
if b > 10:
    b = int(input('Nota invalida digite novamente: \n'))
c = int(input('digite a terceira nota: \n'))
if c > 10:
    c = int(input('Nota invalida digite novamente: \n'))
d = int(input('digite a quarta nota: \n'))
if d > 10:
    d = int(input('Nota invalida digite novamente: \n'))

media= (a + b + c + d) / 4

if media < 11:
    print('a media é : {}\n'.format(media))
else:
    print('uma ou mais notas não sao validas')
```

Answer (score -2):

Poderia criar uma função auxiliar para manter o usuário em um loop enquanto não houver uma leitura de um inteiro com sucesso. Segue um exemplo de como essa função auxiliar pode ser implementada.

```
def lerInteiro():
     while True:
        try:
            a  = int(input('digite a nota: \n'))
            if a >= 0 and a <= 10:
                return a
            raise Exception
        except:
            print("Não foi possível ler o valor digitado como uma nota válida")
```

depois poderia utilizar a função auxiliar para ler os valores das notas em seu código, estou exemplificando aqui a leitura de apenas um valor, mas pode ser feito na leitura de todas as variáveis (a,b,c,d):

```
a = lerInteiro()
```

### Explicando o código:

Colocamos o usuário em um laço de repetição *while* para que enquanto não ocorra uma conversão (para inteiro) com sucesso.

Adicionalmente coloquei uma verificação de intervalo dos valores aceitos para este caso aceitamos apenas valores entre 0 e 10.

Utilizamos um bloco try, para garantir que o valor digitado pode ser convertido para valor inteiro. Caso contrário mostramos uma mensagem de erro direcionando o usuário para tentar resolver o problema.